# Classic asp null becomes DBNull.Value on COM call

Tags: .net, asp-classic, com

We have a big project of legacy classic ASP code, mostly in jscript
Some of functionality was moved to .NET and called via COM from classic ASP

I have just found out that js null from classic ASP is passed as DBNull.Value to .NET code.

How do I pass "real" null?

.NET class:

```
[Guid("12345678-1234-3315-8F2D-8C954E9844E7")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public partial class Factory : IDisposable
{
    public void Inspect(object obj)
    {
          //breakpoint here;
    }
}
```

asp code:

```
var DOTNETAPI = new ActiveXObject(progID);
var val = null;
DOTNETAPI.Inspect(val);
```

Comment: UPD: Found a way - undefined becomes null after marshalling from js

Comment: Please post this as a new answer and accept it so that others will know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

undefined becomes null after marshalling from jscript